# ¿Por qué no me carga las imágenes cuando presiono f5 en Visual Studio Code escribiendo html?

Tags: html

estoy empezando a realizar mi primer página siguiendo un tutorial de youtube pero cuando inicio la depuración en Visual Studio Code en vez de aparecer las imágenes, me aparecen en gris y no me las carga.
Muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <body>
    <!-- Agregar enlace a imágenes de gatos-->
<h2>  App De Gatos</h2>
<main>
    <h3>Imágenes de gatos</h3>
    <P>Haz click aquí para ver más <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/" target="_blank" rel="noonpener noonreferrer">imágenes de gatos.</a></P>
    <img src= "https://as01.epimg.net/diarioas/imagenes/2022/04/20/actualidad/1650466413_240889_1650466661_noticia_normal_recorte1.jpg" alt="Gato pachorra">

    <img src= "C:\Users\User\Documents\Programación Web CFL402\Curso de HTML y CSS\lasagna.png" alt= "Lasagna">
    


    </main>
  </body>
  <head>
    
  </head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

La imagen no le va a cargar porque siempre está referenciada a la carpeta public de su proyecto. Esta línea:

```
<img src= "C:\Users\User\Documents\Programación Web CFL402\Curso de HTML y CSS\lasagna.png" alt= "Lasagna">
```

Debería ser algo como:

```
<img src= ".\lasagna.png" alt= "Lasagna">
```

Hay una extensión para VSCode que se llama LiveServer. Debería darle una mirada.

Answer (score -3):

Para poder poner una imagen en una página web esta tiene que estar en un servidor público, ya que si solo se encuentra en tu dispositivo al resto de la gente que intente visualizarla (desde otro equipo y al no tener esa ruta en su equipo) no le saldrá nada.

Recomendación, si es una imagen que tienes en tu equipo y no está en internet subirla a una página como imgur y utilixar el link que te proporciona (entre todos los links el que se llama Direct Link terminado en .jpg, .png...).